# properly using Meteorjs with Reactjs?

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I've added the 'meteor-react' package and am going over the Microscope tutorial. Along the way, I'm just replacing the Blaze template steps with React, but I'm unsure of how to do it properly such that Collections will be reactive with the Reactjs framework.

"Posts" is a mongo collection.
In my main.js:

```
// Startup application
Meteor.startup(function() {
   var target = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; 
   var data = Posts.find().fetch();  // RACE CONDITION occurs here.
   React.renderComponent(new StreamAtom({ "data": data}), target);
});
```

In StreamAtom.jsx react component, the "data" is simply set as the initial state.

Problem:

There is a race condition with the Posts.find().fetch() so most of the time the page doesn't render. There's no callbacks in Meteor and Blaze takes care of " Posts.find() " without callbacks, so What am I missing?

Also, how do I use only Posts.find() without the fetch? Since fetch() returns an array of results instead of a Mongo cursor, I'm afraid React won't actually be reactive to the changes to the collection.

Thanks a lot in advance,

I hope this will help me to understand meteor better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap the React render function call into `Tracker.autorun` - this is how most of Meteor's client-side reactivity happens:

```
// Startup application
Meteor.startup(function() {
  Tracker.autorun(function () {
   var target = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; 
   var data = Posts.find().fetch();  // RACE CONDITION occurs here.
   React.renderComponent(new StreamAtom({ "data": data}), target);
  });
});
```

A comprehensive guide on Tracker: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/tracker

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. I'm surprised that the tutorial doesn't mention it upfront. Does Blaze run this internally?

Comment: Blaze is seamlessly running Autoruns on helpers and data contexts, and then patches DOM minimally w/o explicit rendering.

Comment: How do you get JSX transform working automatically as part of the Meteor build system?

Comment: @GiantElk you can add a package like this one: https://atmospherejs.com/reactjs/react, it integrates the react build tool-chain

Comment: I'll give that package a try, although was hoping for a simpler way to transform JSX . i.e. if I want to use ReactJS with Iron-Router, or just for simple static view web site without accessing pub/sub.

Comment: @GiantElk I have no idea what is preventing you to use the mentioned package with IronRouter.

Comment: No documentation or examples. How would this iron-router call look converted to React-meteor: `this.render('ShowItem', {data: item});` ?

Comment: Here's some other challenges, i.e. how to separate ReactJS components into separate .jsx files: https://github.com/reactjs/react-meteor/issues/55

Comment: ... And how to get react-meteor working with `meteor run android`: https://github.com/reactjs/react-meteor/issues/54

Comment: I give up on Meteor + React for now, just too much messing around, still can't get it working.